# asynctargetingpack and webclient use in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, .net-4.0

I am creating a sample app using vs2012 and targeting .net 4.0 and trying to use BCL portability pack for .net 4.
I have the following code

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string result = await client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("some uri"));
```

I am under the impression, this should work, but I get the following error
"Cannot await 'void'    "

What am I missing?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Consider using HttpClient Class from HTTP Client Libraries NuGet package (Microsoft.Net.Http).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you call returns `void` and is event-driven... this makes it incompatible with `await` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx)).

You either implement the event [`DownloadStringCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringcompleted.aspx) (without `await`) **OR** you use [`DownloadStringTaskAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194294.aspx) instead which is designed to be used together with `await`.

Comment: Another way of saying this is that `DownloadStringAsync` is [EAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx) while `DownloadStringTaskAsync` is [TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx), and only TAP methods work directly with `async`/`await`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.So, I would have to use TaskCompletionSource and create an extension method so that I can use async and await.